# How to create many columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, image, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

[image: dataframe]

But I want each of those pixels in each row to have separate columns. So it would be something like this

```
0 129 179 242 128 178 241
1 104 93  75  101 90  72
2 172 159 176 171 158 175
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be that efficient but you can convert those tuples into list, extend them and then apply series i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':[[(1,2,3,),(4,5,6)],[(4,5,6),(7,8,9)]],'two':['a','b']})

                      one two
0  [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]   a
1  [(4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]   b

df['one'] = df['one'].apply(lambda x : sum([list(i) for i in x],[]))

new_df = df['one'].apply(pd.Series).assign(two=df['two'])

new_df 
  two  0  1  2  3  4  5
0   a  1  2  3  4  5  6
1   b  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to get the values of the `'Images_H'` column, convert them to an array (which will be 3d instead of 2d due to the tuples inside the list) and then reshape it to a 2d array. Starting from a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':[[(1,2,3,),(4,5,6)],[(4,5,6),(7,8,9)],[(4,5,10),(7,15,9)]],'two':['a','b','c']})
df
                        one two
0    [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]   a
1    [(4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]   b
2  [(4, 5, 10), (7, 15, 9)]   c
```

The method woud look like that, first the number of rows is calculated for the reshape, and then the new dataframe is generated:

```
n = len(df['one'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(df['one'].values.tolist()).reshape((n,-1))).assign(two=df['two'])

df1
   0  1   2  3   4  5 two
0  1  2   3  4   5  6   a
1  4  5   6  7   8  9   b
2  4  5  10  7  15  9   c
```